# edit an the text inside an drawing shape in c#

Tags: c#, drawing

how i can edit the text of a drawing rectangle (class digram) when i double click on it ? this the code in c# how i draw the class digram

```
g1.DrawRectangle(pen, x1, y1, width, height); 
g1.DrawString("class Name", new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x1,(y1 +5)); //TextRenderingHint 
g1.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1 + 23, x1 + width, y1 + 23); 
g1.DrawString("+ attribute :type ", new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x1, (y1 + 30)); 
g1.DrawLine(pen, x1, y1 + 48, x1 + width, y1 + 48); 
g1.DrawString("+ operation (args list):return", new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x1, (y1 + 55));
```

Comment: Please re-format your code..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't.
You are not working with variables, but you are rendering an output on the screen -> you painted something. You would need to locate the area, erase it and redraw your string.
If you want to edit your content, you would need to integrate controls like Textboxes or labels into your diagram.